# I trained a small data set cat and dog classification model, but I predict the new picture will only output two values, or 1 or 0

Tags: python, keras, predict

I've trained a small data set of cat and dog classification model, but I predict the new picture will only output two values, or 1 or 0.

### Code Prediction Code

```
from keras.models import load_model
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.applications.vgg16 import preprocess_input, 
decode_predictions
import numpy as np

img_path = 'mitosis.140.jpg'
img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(150, 150))
x = image.img_to_array(img)
x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
x = preprocess_input(x)

model =load_model('mitosis_.h5')


classes = model.predict_classes(x)

print classes
```

### My prediction

[image]

Comment: so what your question?

Comment: My question is: I think my prediction code is wrong, the correct result should not tell me the input picture is a cat or dog is the probability of the probability is much, I do not understand what is the meaning of the output of 1 or 0

Answer (score 0):

You are using the function `predict_classes()`. As it clearly says, it predicts classes.

Try therefore :

```
probs = model.predict(x)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I tried, but no matter what I enter the picture, predict results are always 1, is not my code is a problem?

Comment: In your problem you say that you get 0 sometimes... it changed?

Comment: I know my problem, I use the classification model of cat and dog training, and download data have been added over the label, the cat's label is 0, the dog tag is 1, so the output is representative of the classification results, thank you